# Creating a column to dynamically count the occurrence of uniqueID in PowerBI when filters are applied

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a dynamic column/measure in powerBI which calculates the number of occurrence of unique ID based on the filters applied. I have the following subset of a data.

[image]

So now if filter Location column for Walking, the column should display
15584 --> 2
34732 --> 2

But if Location column has filter as Walking and/or Car, then the column should have data as
15584 --> 2
34732 --> 4

Is it possible to create such dynamic column/measure at row level in PowerBI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Table'[UNIQUEID]), REMOVEFILTERS('Table'[Product])
)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this has really helped me solve the first part of the problem. But now I have one more column say "Weight" which has some value which is unique for each UniqueID. For example, let's say 15584 = 49606 and 34372 = 103496. What I want to achieve is I want to divide the Weight value with the Measure. Is this possible?

Comment: You're probably best posting a brand new question.